# ssh connection handle pexpect in python

Tags: python, linux, ssh, cisco, pexpect

I was trying to automate a system where we have a linux box but customized.. to go to shell we have to pass some input. like below:

```
tanuj$ ssh admin@10.10.10.10
Used by Tanuj

Password: 

command line interface

app > en
app # config t
app (config) #
```

I have written a script using pexpect in python. I am able to login and execute the command

```
pexpect.sendline("ls -lrt")
pexpect.expect("#")
```

but when i am using `pexpect.before()`  .. is getting nothing .. when the command output is long and also i could see the `pexpect.before` has also got the command in it.

any idea how to solve this.. or is there any other python module which i can use to automation a ssh session like i have here.

i also tried using paramiko but it did not work because we have a to execute some commands before we can reach to normal shell prompt.

Comment: Could there be a `#` in the output somewhere before the next prompt?

Comment: I checked that too .. but its not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the similar problem. I was about to ask the question. You are using a # sign in your

```
pexpect.expect('#')
```

This # sign comments everything written after it. Further I guess you should create a child process to spawn a process, Like(I don't know if I'm right in your situation):

```
child=pexpect.spawn('ssh admin@10.10.10.10')
child.expect('prompt_expected_by_you')     # put in the prompt you expect after sending SSH
child.sendline('your_password')
child.expect('Prompt_expected_by_you')
child.sendline('ls -ltr')
child.expect('Prompt_expected_by_you')
print child.before,            # , will keep continue your newline print
print child.after
child.sendline('exit')
child.expect('Prompt_expected_by_you')
child.sendline('exit')
child.expect('Prompt_expected_by_you')   # may not be required
child.close                              # close the child session
```

I have successfully used these commands in FTP, but not able to print result of 'LS -LTR' in SSH. I guess i'll have to initiate a shell, but not sure. Any progress on your side?

## Could someone help???

Comment: `#` doesn't start a comment if it appears in a string.